# Java Maven throws "package does not exist"

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-errors, package, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have an APIClient class autogenerated from an OpenAPI yml file.  Compiling was successful but running the app throws exceptions "java: package com.google.gson.reflect does not exist" and "java: package okhttp3 does not exist".  The pom file contains these two packages.  The digitalform ords client used the same codes but worked fine.  I compared these two pom files and there are no differences.  why does it throw runtime errors?

Error message:

```
C:\jag\jag-rsbc-digital-forms-vips-integration-17\jag-vips-client\src\jag-vips-client\target\generated-sources\openapi\src\main\java\ca\bc\gov\open\jag\ordsvipsclient\api\DisclosureApi.java:25:31
java: package com.google.gson.reflect does not exist
C:\jag\jag-rsbc-digital-forms-vips-integration-17\jag-vips-client\src\jag-vips-client\target\generated-sources\openapi\src\main\java\ca\bc\gov\open\jag\ordsvipsclient\api\DisclosureApi.java:93:19
java: package okhttp3 does not exist
```

POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Compiling was *not* successful; these are compilation errors against Java source files, not runtime errors; they originate from the Java compiler, not Maven; they are error messages, not exceptions; and they were shown, not thrown.

Comment: Thank you. Compiling was successful.  Running 'mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip' built jars,  but running the application threw this exceptions.

Comment: This OpenAPI module is a git submodule. If I run this submodule as an individual application, the application is running fine, but if running it as submodule, startup throws exceptions,  "java: package com.google.gson.reflect does not exist" and "java: package okhttp3 does not exist".

Answer (score 0):

after clone/rebuild the application, I got everything working now. Intellij is just weird.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you can use maven command line application. Its name is `mvn`. All you have to do is change CWD(current working directory) to your project directory

```
$ cd /../../your_project_dir
```

And you can run `mvn` here. It's simple. IntelliJ and Eclipse use cache mechanism everywhere. Because of caching problems such problems can occur.